# jQuery - Enabling, disabling and exclusive checkboxes in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following [Table](http://prntscr.com/4nlthx).

What I am trying to do is to disable the "Every ..." columns of checkboxes by default and then enabling them only when the "Weekly" checkbox is selected. As well as that, I want the "Less often", "Monthly" and "Weekly" to be mutually exclusive and "Never" exclusive to the rest.

Fiddle: [HTML code](http://jsfiddle.net/dt2e2v6g/1/)

So far I have the following ideas:

- make a group of all the "Every ..." disable them.
- if checkbox weekly is clicked, given its id, enable the "every" group
- give all the less often, monthly and weekly the same name, and make
  them mutually exclusive

As far as the coding goes, I have the following scripts:

#### Enabling set of checkboxes ("Every...") when a specific checkbox is clicked ("Weekly")

This one is for the case of Weekly, enabling the every other day of the week. The question that I'm having is how to apply it to all the rows of the table, not just to one.

```
$(function() {
  enable_cb();
  $("#group1").click(enable_cb);
});

function enable_cb() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $("input.group1").removeAttr("disabled");

  } else {
      $("input.group1").attr("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

If all of the "Every" are in a group, and the group id is the first checkbox of Weekly, that would enable all of the checkboxes on the other rows as well. What is there to do about this or what other method should I approach?

#### Mutually Exclusive

I want three of the checkboxes to be mutually exclusive with eachother. I thought of naming them the same and then just apply the script below. Nevertheless, I want this to apply to all of the rows of the table.

```
$("input[name=myCheckbox]").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this), 
        wasChecked = $this.attr("checked") === "checked";
    $("input[name=myCheckbox]:checked").removeAttr("checked");
    if (wasChecked) {
        $this.attr("checked", "checked");
    }
});
```

I am a beginner with jQuery so any insight is welcomed.

Comment: show your html as well

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, what would you do?

Answer (score 0):

I should add an id each checkbox. Something like this:

check1_1 check1_2...
check2_1 check2_2...

So you can run in a bucle to check or uncheck each one depending on what you receives in some of them.

$("#check"+i+"_"+X).... //i = row and X = column

Make a for to create all of check functions when page shows and inside call to a unique function with 2 arguments, row and column clicked to make any comparisson.

Comment: Can you give me an example?